# TypeORM: cascade update like soft delete

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

Is it possible to cascade like soft delete when removing from parent entity?

Lets say I have:

```
class ParentEntity {
  @OneToMany(() => ChildEntity, (ce) => ca.parentEntity)
  childrenEntities: ChildEntity[];
}

class ChildEntity {
  @ManyToOne(() => ParentEntity, (pe) => pe.childrenEntities)
  parentEntity: ParentEntity;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt?: Date;
}
```

Is it possible to perform soft delete of ChildEntity from ParentEntity?
Below implementation sets a parentId in ChildEntity to NULL instead of setting date in deletedAt.

For example like:

```
//find parent 
const parent = this.repo.find(...)

//remove from childrenEntities
parent.childrenEntities.splice(0, 1); 

//save parent
this.repo.save(parent)
```

Comment: anyone any ideas?

Comment: Why not performing the soft delete directly on the childrens ? You do not need to update the parent, but only the childrens.